# Unable to import file from ember-cli generated utils folder

Tags: ember-cli

I have generated a utility using `ember generate util` and I'm trying to import it in another file, but I get a build error.

My utility (`app/utils/swapi-adapter.js`):

```
import Ember from 'ember';

/* global $ */
export default Ember.Object.extend({
  base: 'http://swapi.co/api/',

  get: function(uri) {
    var url = uri;

    // make sure to append url
    if(url.indexOf(this.get('base')) !== -1) {
       url = this.get('base') + url;
    }

    return $.getJSON(url);
  }
});
```

The route I'm trying to import it to: (`app/routes/test-api.js`)

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import SWAPI from 'utils/swapi-adapter';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: {},
  actions: {
    test: function(url) {
      SWAPI.get(url);
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the "correct" way to import a utility is actually:

```
import SWAPI from '[app-name]/utils/swapi-adapter';
```

Although in case of an adapter, this is probably not best.

Comment: After a lot of searching ,i found this to be correct. That really helped. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need a relative path, since the adapter is in a different directory than the route:

```
import SWAPI from '../utils/swapi-adapter';
```

You might consider using [dependency injection](http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/dependency-injection-and-service-lookup/) to give all your routes access to the adapter.